# How to set focus on a TextBox when a form opens?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, focus

I want to set focus on a textbox. I tried this code:

```
textbox1.Focus();
```

and put it below

```
InitializeComponent();
```

but the textbox does not get focus. Why is it not getting focus?

Comment: call `textbox1.focus()` inside `Form1_Load` method

Comment: where can I find `Form_Load` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try doing `textbox1.select()` on form1_load method.

Comment: The better way is to set thet ab index t of textbox t...o 0

Answer (score 6):

An element can't be focused until it has been created in the back (that is, Win32. A *handle* must be created). Therefore you need to put this kind of code in the [`Form.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

After `InitializeComponent`:

```
this.Load += this.Form_Load;
```

Then create this method:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textbox1.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've put in the wrong place, try putting in [Form load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event

You can find the form load event here:

[image]